# Internet Explorer 9 Compatibility mode

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-9

Some sites look bad in IE9 (GMail being one). I found that pressing F12 to get the developer console then switching from compatibility mode to "Internet Explorer 9" mode fixed the problem. However, when I restart IE this setting is lost.

How do I make it persistent?

I am on Windows 7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under the tools menu (not the gear icon in the upper right corner) you can use the compatibility settings option to add sites to be always viewed in compatibility view or set all sites to be viewed that way.  If you cannot find the tools menu, click 'Alt' to show the command bar once or right click the title bar and choosing 'Command Bar' from the menu to show the command bar all the time.

Comment: I cannot find it at all - the only thing I find under tools is the developer console, which you have to keep changing when you visit a site.

Comment: I'm running Version 9.0.8112.16421 and the compatibility view settings are 4 items above the F12 developer tools option.

Comment: Ok - well that must be new then. In that place I have Zoom

Comment: Weird - I am running the same version.

Comment: When I first installed 9 I got a few prompts to customize it, maybe it was an option in there.

Comment: Edited answer to make it clear that the tools menu is not the same thing as the gear icon menu in the upper right corner.

Comment: Great - that is so confusing to have two menus with the same name (especially as one is hidden!). Anyway the trick was to uncheck the "include latest lists from Microsoft" in the compatibility view settings.